# Is keeping average current low a way to avoid damage to PSU and MOSFETs?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, pwm

Here’s the scenario: I have to power two heating plates which drain 18 A each but the PSU is only rated 32 A. The initial plan was to attach each plate to a MOSFET module rated 30 A and control them by only turning on one plate at a time. Then my mate came up with the idea of latching both plates to one MOSFET and controlling it with a PWM signal, like 50-60%. This way the average current will be lower and no damage will occurr.
Now I’m a little debated because on one hand I know that generally overcurrent damage comes from overheating (Joule's law and stuff). So if average current is lower, so will thermal effects be.
On the other hand, even if very short, they are still 36 A pulses, 4 A above PSU's rating and 6 A over MOSFET's.
So, I’d like some expert opinion on this.
Thank you in advance.

PS: If you're wondering, I can't use only one plate beacause the surface to heat is pretty wide. About the PSU, I *could* get a bigger one, but i got this, out of my PlayStation (RIP), taking dust for a while and I'd really like to put it to work.

Comment: And the heating plates are spec'd for 12 V?

Comment: @MiNiMe Sorry, totally forgot about voltages. The MOSFETS handle 12 to 50V, the PSU feeds 12V and the plates can run on 12 or 24V, depending on which lugs are powered.

Answer (score 1):

PWM is a process in which we reduce the total power by reducing the percentage of time power is supplied. In order for it to work well, there needs to be something to smooth the power out. Things like LEDs work really well, because the human eye naturally averages the brightness it sees (for flashes faster than 60Hz). Whether it will work with your heating plates somewhat depends on what the heating plate is and how the PSU behaves.

Let's say the plates are just resistors, then PWM is probably a great way to control them. However, if they're made of a long coil of wire, they might have a large inductance which would make them resist the switching of the PWM, and you might not get the power out you expect, or you might get unforeseen problems. This is really worth looking into, as switching inductors can induce high voltages

PSUs also behave differently when they see an overload. Some shut off altogether, which we don't want. Some limit their voltage to keep the power in range which would be ok, but it would result in less power being available. It wouldn't be a good idea to simply set the overload and hope the PSU could handle it, even for a very short time, as it would stress the PSU and make it likely to fail, it's worth adding some circuitry to match the power requirements.

Now you clearly don't need to get the maximum power out, but you're looking for a way to power both plates. I'd have to say the easiest thing to do would be to go with the one plate to each mosfet plan and drive them one after the other, on a nice slow rate (like 0.25Hz) with something to ensure they're never on at the same time). If you want to have them both running off the same MOSFET you'd need some kind of switching to avoid overloading the PSU, but if you go down that road you end up making a second PSU, which isn't trivial at 384W.

You could go for a halfway option, where you use a lot of passives to try and filter the power out. You don't need to get from a PWM square wave all the way to pure DC, you just need to drop the peaks down to within the PSU's acceptable level which is possible. If you're using 60% PWM, for which the power is 36/32 = 112.5% of the max during on I can see that being very possible.

Finally, MOSFETs are usually pretty happy being driven over their max DC value in pulses. The data sheet will tell you how far, and at what duty and frequency different overloads can be.

Answer (score 0):

You will put a lot of stress on the PSU since it will in reality be an overload 50-60% of the time. A SMPS is built to keep a steady voltage, and in this scenario the voltage will fluctuate along the PWM, putting stress on it. With two MOSFETs taking turn the power drain will be much more even, but this is a more complicated setup.

A better way is what you say to use a more powerful PSU, preferable with a good deal of margin above 32 A, to avoid running it at 100%.